# Is it possible to display the caret outside of token, when it is positioned right after its last character?

Tags: css, contenteditable, text-styling, letter-spacing, lexicaljs

I have a `TokenNode`, which is pretty much just a regular TextNode, but with some additional styles:

```js
  createDOM(config: EditorConfig): HTMLElement {
    const dom = super.createDOM(config);

    dom.style.background = "lightgrey";
    dom.style.padding = "5px 10px";
    dom.style.border = "1px solid darkgrey";
    dom.style.borderRadius = "8px";
    dom.style.margin = "0 5px";

    return dom;
  }
```

When the caret is positioned after the last character of `TokenNode`, it is visually displayed inside the node:
[image]

I would like it to visually display outside of the node's borders, something like this (I added a space after the node to demonstrate the point):
[image]

A sandbox can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-move-caret-outside-of-token-h45m9m

I tried adding an empty `::after` pseudo-element to the node, and I also tried applying letter-spacing to the last character, but neither of those actually moved the caret outside of the node borders.

Is this possible to achieve in a stable manner (in a way that can be flawlessly managed while updating the editor's content), preferably with pure css?

Comment: Could you put runnable code direct into your question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your sandbox seems to have an error, and in any case it won't help future readers as it may get deleted or altered.

Comment: @AHaworth Ooops, my bad, I accidentally messed up the sandbox, I made some further experiments on it without forking it ‍♂️. It's fixed now. I will look into the snippet later and try to add it - I didn't know you can make them with React and include third libraries, but seems you can, thank you very much for pointing me to that :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?